# Need a way to toggle a class for a paragraph (block) with custom button

Tags: quill

I am trying to make a simple button that toggles a class on the selected paragraph. In this case for a spoiler function, that marks up the paragraph differently.
I haven't been able to find any straightforward answers to this. Is there really no simple way to do that?

Best I have come up with is using a ClassAttributor, but that seems to insist on using a prefix for the class which bugs me a little for semantic reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the block blot and change the class name.

```
  class Content extends Block {}
  Content.blotName = 'content';
  Content.tagName = 'div';
  Content.className = 'hiii';
  Quill.register(Content, true);
```

Check this jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hassansalem/kmxzh3tn/2/

I hope it is what you are searching for. ✌️

Comment: Thanks. It works initially, but I would very much like to use P tags instead of DIVs. And if I change the tagName in you example to 'p' it only applies the class. Won't remove it again.

Comment: I don't think that is possible , because <p> is the default tag that Quill uses when no custom block is defined. But you can still use section or any block-level elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Elements

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try and find a way to work around it.